# Finding the combination of N numbers that their sum give number R

Tags: algorithm, search, combinations

How it would be possible to find/guess the combination of `N` numbers such as `5 or 7 or whatever` that gives a final number `R`?

For example, determine `N = 5` and `R = 15`

The one possible result/guess that the `5` numbers in which their summation give `15` would be `{1,2,3,4,5}`

Comment: Is the array needed to be consecutive?

Comment: No at all, any possible combinations @SơnNinh

Comment: Pick randomly N-1 numbers, nth = R - sum(N-1)

Comment: It's not clear to me, would you please write code with an example @SơnNinh

Comment: If the numbers are floats, take any N random floats in (0,1) add them together, and multiply by R/(sum of R random floats).

Answer (score 3):

To get *n* floating point numbers that total a target *r*:

1. Fill an array of size *n* with random numbers in (0,1).
2. Find the total of the array. Call this *T*.
3. Multiply every element in the array by *r*/*T*.

-edit (thanks @ruakh) -

4. To account for floating point error, total the array again, calculate the delta from target, and update the array to correct for it however you like. This will be a very small number. It's probably fine to update the first element of the array, but if you want you could spread it across the full array.

Comment: +1, but note that due to floating-point roundoff error, the results may not add up to *exactly* the target number. (In fact, I think they more likely *won't* than *will*, but I'm not sure.) I think you can fix this by finding the least element in the result and replacing it with *r* minus the sum of the other elements. (Because it's the least element, it's guaranteed to have to have enough floating-point precision for that . . . but calculating it might be tricky!)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by backtracking, this is really slow, because it looks for all combinations, but if you only want one combination use K-1 0' and N, this sum = N

```
n = 15
k = 2
array = [0] * k

def comb (len, sum):
    if len == k - 1:
        array[len] = sum
        print(array)
        return

    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        if sum - i >= 0:
            array[len] = i
            comb(len + 1, sum - i)

comb(0, n)
```

Comment: It didn't work if n is a float number, giving this error: `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: yes it doesn't work if n is float because if n is float there are infinite combinations, you only need one combination?

Comment: Yes, and better if the combination of numbers are uniques (no any identical numbers)

Comment: you can choose K-1 consecutive numbers and the last number choose N-K*(K-1)/2, this last formule is because 1+2+3+4+...+K-1 = K*(K-1)/2

Answer (score 0):

Python code

```
import random
N = 5
R = 7
result = random.sample(range(0, int(R)), N-1)
result.append(R - sum(result))
```

Comment: What if R is a float number?

Comment: It gives me this error if R is float: `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` at this line `result = random.sample(range(0, R), N-1)`

Comment: It now gives this error `ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative` on the same line as above